# Сбросить настройки сочетаний клавиш в SSMS

Tags: sql

В какой-то момент сочетание клавиш "CTRL+R" в SSMS 2012, которое скрывает/отображает окно результатов запроса, перестало работать, и больше не скрывает его. Никаких обновлений не устанавливалось. По ссылке [Сочетания клавиш среды SQL Server Management Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms174205(v=sql.120).aspx) ничего толкового нет.

**Вопрос** прост: Как вернуть эту возможность?

Answer (score 1):

Решение нашел самостоятельно. Исправить это можно 2-мя способами:

1) Можно проверить и установить соответствующую настройку, или

2) Сбросить все настройки сочетаний клавиш:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Может быть, кому-то пригодится.